# Using @charset "UTF-8" returns an error

Tags: css, less

I am trying to compile my `.less` document, and I am getting an error when trying to use `@charset "UTF-8";`.

I want to be sure my document is encoded correctly because of the way I embed my fonts. src: local('☺'), url(...);

Any ideas?

Comment: For anybody who landed on this page: LESS seams to only support lower case charset declaration: `@CHARSET` throws an error, `@charset` is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

This seems to be a big, they say to fix it in the next version:

More Info:
https://less.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/8-charset-error

> Thanks for posting, this is fixed in
>   the upcoming 2.0 version, which should
>   be released sometime this month. It is
>   indeed due to @charset not being
>   parsed as a directive.

That comment by the LESS team was published on:

```
May 05, 2010 @ 05:50 AM
```

So it should be fixed in recent version. Make sure that you are using the **latest** version of it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
html {
}
@charset "utf-8";
//your style
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6f6f6f;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to format your code properly.